# How can I using Pig scripts to generate nested Avro field?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig, My input data is in the format as

```
Record1:
{
  label:int,
  id: long
},
Record 2:
{
 ...
}
...
```

And what I want as output is to get

```
Record 1:
{
  data:{
    label:int,
    id:long
  }
}, 
Record 2:
{
  ...
}
...
```

I tried:

```
result = FOREACH input GENERATE (id, label) AS data;
```

but this results in a nested tuple structure that looks as below:

```
Record 1:
{
  data:{
   TUPLE_1:{
      label:int,
      id: long
   }
  }
}
```

How could I get rid of the one more bag as "TUPLE_1", that looks like I missed a trivial setting.

Comment: How are you getting these structures? Are you using `DESCRIBE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is like this:

First of all to create an avro file with a certain schema, I make sure I do the following schema configuration for AvroStorage:

```
STORE sth INTO 'someplace' USING AvroStorage('schema','
  {
    ### AN AVRO SCHEMA JSON STRING ###
  }
');
```

I found using such indentation really helps to make the schema definition cleaner. And also I need to make sure I escape all special characters, especially for quotes (they may exist in "doc", that's tricky).

Then to make sth has the correct pig structure to be stored, I need to construct the entire data structure properly. One good trick could be using `DESCRIBE` if there already some examples of the target data files. In my previous question, the code should look like this:

```
in = LOAD '$INPUT_PATHS' USING AvroStorage();
in = FOREACH in GENERATE foo.label AS label, bar.id AS id;
out = FOREACH in GENERATE TOMAP('id', (long)id, 'label', (chararray)label) AS data;
RMF $OUTPUT_PATH;
STORE out INTO '$OUTPUT_PATH USING AvroStorage('schema',
  {
    "type": "records",
    "name": "XXItem",
    "namespace": "com.xxx.xxx",
    "fields": [
      {
       "name": "data",
       "type":  {"type": "map", "values" : ["string", "long", "int"]}
      }
    ]
  }
');
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify schema when you STORE the data.
If you use org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage, it can take schema definition as parameter.

```
result = FOREACH input GENERATE label:int, id:long;
STORE result INTO 'result.avro' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage('schema', '{"type": "record","name": "data","fields": [{"name": "label","type": "int"},{"name": "id", "type": "long"}]}');
```